# SQL: Query multiple tables with a conditional result field (Sorry I don't even know how to ask it correctly)

Tags: sql, mysql, multiple-tables

Taking into account the following example tables:

USERS:

| id_user | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul |
| 2 | Caroline |

TRAVEL:

| id_travel | id_user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

TRAVEL_DAYS:

| id_tdays | id_travel | day_has_activities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | no |
| 2 | 1 | no |
| 3 | 1 | yes |
| 4 | 2 | no |
| 5 | 2 | no |
| 6 | 3 | no |
| 7 | 3 | yes |
| 8 | 4 | yes |

If I do the following query:

```
SELECT 
t.id_travel,
u.name,
td.day_has_activities
FROM travel t
left join users u on u.id_user = t.id_user
left join travel_days td on td.id_travel = t.id_travel
```

Since trip number one has three days and trip two, as well as trip three, have two days each the result would be something like this:

| id_travel | id_user | day_has_activities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | no |
| 1 | Paul | no |
| 1 | Paul | yes |
| 2 | Paul | no |
| 2 | Paul | no |
| 3 | Caroline | no |
| 3 | Caroline | yes |

I need to have unique trip rows, so I thought about using DISTINC but the has_activities field shows me "yes" or "no" randomly.

**I need to know for each trip if it contains any days with activities so the perfect result would be this :**

| id_travel | id_user | travel_has_activities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | yes |
| 2 | Paul | no |
| 3 | Caroline | yes |

I tried something like this, but it doesn't runs:

```
SELECT 
t.id_travel,
u.name,
if ((select count(td.day_has_activities) from t where td.day_has_activities like 'yes') > 0, 'yes', 'no') as travel_has_activities
FROM travel t
left join users u on u.id_user = t.id_user
left join travel_days td on td.id_travel = t.id_travel
```

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, MAX().,

Comment: Could you please tag the RDBMS (oracle, sql server ... ) you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting the maximum value of **day_has_activities** for each **id_travel** and then join this dataset with your tables using a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
select t.id_travel, u.name, case when day_has_activities = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as travel_has_activities
from travel t
left join users u on u.id_user = t.id_user
left join (
  select id_travel, max(case when day_has_activities = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end ) as day_has_activities
  from travel_days
  group by id_travel
) td on td.id_travel = t.id_travel
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9rvZsh8j)

Answer (score 0):

CTE part, I used your query to joins table, and second part I used self join and exist function to check yes values exist in previous table or not and group by according to first and second table

```
WITH example as (
SELECT 
t.id_travel,
u.name,
td.day_has_activities
FROM travel t
left join users u on u.id_user = t.id_user
left join travel_days td on td.id_travel = t.id_travel
)


SELECT
    id_travel,
    id_user,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM example AS t2
        WHERE t2.id_travel = t1.id_travel AND t2.day_has_activities = 'yes'
    ) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS day_has_activities
FROM
    example AS t1
GROUP BY
    id_travel,
    id_user
ORDER by id_travel,
id_user
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that `'yes' > 'no'` for strings, you can just select `MAX(td.day_has_activities)`
while grouping by the other two columns (making them "distinct").

```
SELECT t.id_travel, u.name, max(td.day_has_activities) as has_activities
FROM travel t
left join users u on u.id_user = t.id_user
left join travel_days td on td.id_travel = t.id_travel
group by t.id_travel, u.name
```

| id_travel | name | has_activities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | yes |
| 2 | Paul | no |
| 3 | Caroline | yes |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FLRLexMJ)

If it's possible to have no matches at all in the `travel_days` (That's why you use a LEFT join - right?),
you can use `coalesce(max(td.day_has_activities), 'no')`, making `'no'` the default value.

Another way is to check for an existence of a related row with 'yes' using a subquery in the SELECT clause (*subselect*):

```
SELECT 
  t.id_travel, 
  u.name,
  case
    when exists (
      select *
      from travel_days td
      where td.id_travel = t.id_travel
        and td.day_has_activities = 'yes'
    ) then 'yes' else 'no' 
  end as has_activities
FROM travel t
left join users u on u.id_user = t.id_user
```

This can avoid scanning the entire table, if there are only few matches.